# Trouble with JSON duckduckgo api

Tags: python, json, api

I keep getting

```
"json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
```

when running this, i'm guessing thats because the json right, but idk if thats because of something im doing, or if there is something extra I should be doing to get the json decoded right

```
respon = requests.get("https://duckduckgo-duckduckgo-zero-click-info.p.mashape.com/?callback=process_duckduckgo&format=json&no_html=1&no_redirect=1&q={}&skip_disambig=1".format(query),
headers = secrets.headers).json()
result = respon['Results']['FirstURL']
```

then changing the above to

```
respon = requests.get("https://duckduckgo-duckduckgo-zero-click-info.p.mashape.com/?callback=process_duckduckgo&format=json&no_html=1&no_redirect=1&q={}&skip_disambig=1".format(query),
    headers = headers)
json_object = respon.json
print(json_object)
```

will give me

```
<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>
```

and finally

```
json_object = respon.text
```

gives me this http://pastebin.com/wcJsM8jF

I'm not sure why im not able to get the json.

Comment: try without `callback=process_duckduckgo` - it should give you pure JSON without `process_duckduckgo(...)` (it is called JSONP)

Comment: BTW: it is not `duckduckgo API` but rather `mashup API`. `duckduckgo API` is here: https://duckduckgo.com/api

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, when I switched from mashape api to duckduckgo api. The api key wasn't being accepted for some reason

```
import requests

respon = requests.get('http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q={}&format=json'.format(query))
json_object = respon.json()
result = json_object['Results'][0]['FirstURL']

return await pybot.say(result)
```